# Sailsjs - Dynamically load js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

--> I use sails 0.10.9

I'm trying to load client-side javascript based on the route and controller name, and I want to control if the file exist before including it.

I thought I could use

```
req.options.controller
req.options.action
```

with a middleware in http.js but it's always empty.

So, how do you think I should do ? The aim is to inject the javascript file if it exists. I've tried with a policy with :

```
'*': 'loadScript'
```

But it doesn't load on other page than /

Any help would be really appreciate

Comment: This is a useful question. On a complicated app I work on, we have dependency requirements for each page that allows JS to be compiled and attached on a page-by-page basis. I did not write that code and it's in Java, but I've found it very helpful. I can see how it would come in handy in a larger Sails app.

Comment: Thanks for your consideration. I'm still searching for it.

Comment: For future reference, can you post your `loadScript` policy code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, thanks to @scott-gress for leading me to the good way, here is how I did it.

In `api/policies/serveStatic.js`

```
var fs = require('fs');
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
    if(fs.existsSync(sails.config.local_config.js_dir_path + '/' + req.options.controller + '/common.js'))
        res.locals.scripts.push(sails.config.local_config.js_public_path+ '/' + req.options.controller + '/common.js')
    if(fs.existsSync(sails.config.local_config.css_dir_path + '/' + req.options.controller + '/common.css'))
        res.locals.styles.push(sails.config.local_config.css_public_path+ '/' + req.options.controller + '/common.css')
    if(fs.existsSync(sails.config.local_config.js_dir_path + '/' + req.options.controller + '/' + req.options.action + '.js'))
        res.locals.scripts.push(sails.config.local_config.js_public_path+ '/' + req.options.controller + '/' + req.options.action + '.js')
    if(fs.existsSync(sails.config.local_config.css_dir_path + '/' + req.options.controller + '/' + req.options.action + '.css'))
        res.locals.styles.push(sails.config.local_config.css_public_path+ '/' + req.options.controller + '/' + req.options.action + '.css')
    next();
};
```

And in `config/policies.js`

```
UserController: {
  '*': ['isAuthenticated', "serveStatic"]
},
```

after that, at the end of my `views/layout.ejs` file :

```
<% if(res.locals.scripts) { %>   
    <% res.locals.scripts.forEach(function(script, i ) { %>
        <script src="<%= script %>" ></script>
     <% }) %>
<% }%>
```

The advantage of that is that in any action, I can add my own js script (or css) if I want to.

Comment: Ok, but again, it is important to emphasize that this will only work for views that are served from a controller action.  If you have a route in your **config/routes.js** that points directly to a view, as I demonstrated in my answer, then this won't work because policies are not applied to views--only to actions.

Comment: Do you have any better way to do it ? I don't think I'll have any route that points directly to a static view, or I'll take care of always go throught a controller action.

Comment: This is a fine solution.  I'm just emphasizing the point because it's a common issue that comes up, where developers create a policy and are confused as to why it doesn't apply to their route which they've defined as `"/myRoute": {view: "myView"}`.  As long as you're always going through controllers, this will work great.

Answer (score 0):

The policy is the correct solution; the thing you have to remember about policies is just that they only apply to *controller actions*, not views.  So if you have in your **config/routes.js** file:

```
"/myPage": {view: "myView"}
```

then the policy won't apply when you visit **/myPage**.  Instead, you could do:

```
"/myPage": "StaticController.myView"
```

and in **api/controllers/StaticController.js**:

```
myView: function (req, res) {
    res.view("myView");
}
```

Then the policy will be applied.

Comment: Hello, and thank you for taking time to answer.
I don't understand what you're trying to explain. Could you be more specific ?